# Form not submitted to correct server scgript

Tags: xforms, exist-db, xsltforms

I am trying to test submission of this XForm using an echo service (I have my own echo Xquery script but also tried it with the  web based one you can see in the code example). My checks reveal that the xforms-submit-done event does get fired but  the script in the submission resource attribute doesn't get invoked. Rather it I get a blank page within and the url remains unchanged.

Code is below.

```
<html xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Movie Review Selector</title>
        <model xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms">
            <instance id="movies">
                <movies xmlns="">
                    <movie id=""></movie>
                </movies>
            </instance>
            <submission id="save" resource="http://xformstest.org/cgi-bin/echo.sh" method="post" replace="all">
                <xf:message ev:event="xforms-submit-error" level="modal">Submission Error<xf:output value="event('error-type')"></xf:output>
                </xf:message>
            </submission>
        </model>
    </head>
    <body>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>
                <h3>Movie Selector</h3>
            </legend>
            <group xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms" ref="instance('movies')">
                <repeat nodeset="movie" id="idx">
                    <input ref="@id">
                        <label>Movie Id</label>
                    </input>
                    <trigger>
                        <label>Delete</label>
                        <delete nodeset="." ev:event="DOMActivate"></delete>
                    </trigger>
                </repeat>
                <trigger>
                    <label>Add</label>
                    <action ev:event="DOMActivate">
                        <insert nodeset="movie"></insert>
                        <setvalue ref="movie[last()]/@id" value=""></setvalue>
                    </action>
                </trigger>
                <submit submission="save">
                    <label>Submit</label>
                </submit>
            </group>
        </fieldset>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duw to limitations in browsers, it's not possible to use the POST method and `replace="all"` in XSLTForms.

Instead, you must use `method="xml-urlencoded-post"`, this is a hack that only works for XSLTForms. You won't get a pure XML body in your server, but it'll be in a form field called `postdata`

Take a look to this thread for a deeper explanation: http://sourceforge.net/p/xsltforms/mailman/message/24455248/

The XQuery script should use `request:get-parameter` and `xmldb:decode` to get the document. Something like this:

```
let $p := request:get-parameter( "postdata", "" );
let $doc := xmldb:decode( $p );
return $doc
```

Comment: Thank you. It does now route through to my echo script but eXists request:get-data() which should post the data in the instance returns nothing so I get an empty postdata element. Are you able to shed light on that before I accept the answer?

Comment: I added sample code for the XQuery echo script. HTH